# How to convert .py file to .exe with references to workplace network directories

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

How can I convert a python file that loads data from directories in my workplace network into an executable file that can be used on PCs that don't have python installed?

It would be shared with colleagues who have access to those given directories.

I tried converting it with pyinstaller but I had some issues running the .exe file as administrator.

Thank you in advance

Comment: so what were the issues? PyInstaller should work as it bundles Python inside the .exe file.

Comment: The command prompt would show up for just a second and then nothing else happened, the program didn't run

Comment: what was the exception? there's really not enough information in your question to give any meaningful answer. Please provide [mcve]